# How to use React.memo with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks

I have an input component. Like below. I am now showing unnecessary code. I have to pass a type to while creating input component.

```
const Input = React.memo(
   <T extends string = string>({
      initalValue,
      label,
      name,
      type = "text",
      otherProps = {},
      value,
      inputChangeHandler,
      options
   }: InputProps<T> & {
      value?: string;
      inputChangeHandler: (e: ChangeEvent) => void;
   }) => {

      if (type === "select") {
         return (
            ...
         );
      }
      return (
         ...
      );
   }
);
```

But the above code gives error when I try to use it like

```
    89 |    function renderInput<T extends string = string>(input: InputProps<T>) {
    90 |       return (
  > 91 |          <Input<T>
       |                 ^
    92 |             {...input}
    93 |             key={input.name}
    94 |             value={inputsObject[input.name] as string}
```

The error is

> Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1

I know I am missing something very obvious but I am new to hooks and typescript so can't fix it. Please help me fixing and making me understand the reason for the error.

Comment: You don't need to mention the generic type while rendering the component. It could be as simple as `<Input {...input}` generic type would be automatically inferred from the props you are passing

Comment: @Sumit Kindly consider giving answer. Consider that I have a `Form` component which will have `inputs(array)` as prop. Each element will be of type `InputProps`. `InputProps` have a property called name. Which should only extends from specific string passed the parent `Form` componenet. Tell me if you need my full code...

Comment: it would be great if you could share the code. That way it would be easier to understand the issue